# Implement Physics informed Neural Network using pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I found a very interesting paper, [Physics Informed Deep Learning (Part I): Data-driven Solutions of Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.10561v1.pdf) and want to give it a trial. For this, I create a dummy problem and implement what I understand from the paper.

### Problem Statement

Suppose, I want to solve the ODE `dy/dx = cos(x)` with initial conditions `y(0)=y(2*pi)=0`. Actually, we can easily guess the analytic solution `y(x)=sin(x)`. But I want to see how the model predict the solution using PINN.

```py
# import libraries
import torch
import torch.autograd as autograd # computation graph
import torch.nn as nn  # neural networks
import torch.optim as optim # optimizers e.g. gradient descent, ADAM, etc.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Set default dtype to float32
torch.set_default_dtype(torch.float)
#PyTorch random number generator
torch.manual_seed(1234)
# Device configuration
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
print(device)
```

#### Model Architecture

```py
## Model Architecture
class FCN(nn.Module):
    ##Neural Network
    def __init__(self,layers):
        super().__init__() #call __init__ from parent class 
        # activation function
        self.activation = nn.Tanh()
        # loss function
        self.loss_function = nn.MSELoss(reduction ='mean')
        # Initialise neural network as a list using nn.Modulelist 
        self.linears = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(layers[i], layers[i+1]) for i in range(len(layers)-1)]) 
        self.iter = 0
         # Xavier Normal Initialization
        for i in range(len(layers)-1):
            nn.init.xavier_normal_(self.linears[i].weight.data, gain=1.0)
            # set biases to zero
            nn.init.zeros_(self.linears[i].bias.data)   
    
    # foward pass
    def forward(self,x):
        if torch.is_tensor(x) != True:         
            x = torch.from_numpy(x)                
        a = x.float()
        for i in range(len(layers)-2):  
            z = self.linears[i](a)              
            a = self.activation(z)    
        a = self.linears[-1](a)
        return a
    # Loss Functions
    #Loss PDE
    def lossPDE(self,x_PDE):
      g=x_PDE.clone()
      g.requires_grad=True #Enable differentiation
      f=self.forward(g)
      f_x=autograd.grad(f,g,torch.ones([x_PDE.shape[0],1]).to(device),\
        retain_graph=True, create_graph=True)[0]
      loss_PDE=self.loss_function(f_x,PDE(g))
      return loss_PDE
```

### Generate data

```py
# generate training and evaluation points
x = torch.linspace(min,max,total_points).view(-1,1) 
y = torch.sin(x)
print(x.shape, y.shape)

# Set Boundary conditions:
# Actually for this problem 
# we don't need extra boundary constraint
# as it was concided with x_PDE point & value
# BC_1=x[0,:]
# BC_2=x[-1,:]
# print(BC_1,BC_2)
# x_BC=torch.vstack([BC_1,BC_2])
# print(x_BC)
x_PDE = x[1:-1,:]
print(x_PDE.shape)

x_PDE=x_PDE.float().to(device)
# x_BC=x_BC.to(device)
#Create Model
layers = np.array([1,50,50,50,50,1])
model = FCN(layers)
print(model)
model.to(device)
params = list(model.parameters())
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=lr,amsgrad=False)
```

### Train Neural Network

```py
for i in range(500):
    yh = model(x_PDE)
    loss = model.loss_PDE(x_PDE) # use mean squared error
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    if i%(500/10)==0:
      print(loss)
```

### predict the solution using PINN

```py
# predict the solution beyond training set 
x = torch.linspace(0,max+max,total_points).view(-1,1)
yh=model(x.to(device))
y=torch.sin(x)
#Error
print(model.lossBC(x.to(device)))

y_plot=y.detach().numpy()
yh_plot=yh.detach().cpu().numpy()
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(x,y_plot,color='blue',label='Real')
ax1.plot(x,yh_plot,color='red',label='Predicted')
ax1.set_xlabel('x',color='black')
ax1.set_ylabel('f(x)',color='black')
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', color='black')
ax1.legend(loc = 'upper left')
```

[image: output]

But the end result was so disappointing. The model was unable to learn the simple ODE. I was wondering the model architecture of mine **may have some issue** which I couldn't figure out myself. Can anyone suggest any improvement?

Comment: Debugging and testing deep learning workflows is complex and challenging and not something that is easy to do in a question-comment-answers format like here. Someone would have to commit considerable time to reviewing and testing your code to help at all. I would start with some of the existing implementations of PINNs that you can find online.

Comment: Thanks, @Bill, for your constructive comment. I am aware of Debugging and testing deep learning workflows a bit. But I was surprising, as the paper was considered so good (from my theoretical perspective). But I was thinking, the model should give a better performance for this dummy problem, at least without any further hyperparameter tuning. I was afraid that I have done something wrong with my model architecture

Comment: That's the problem with deep learning. You cannot know whether you have determined the performance of the DNN until you are sure you have implemented the algorithm as intended, eliminated all bugs, chosen all hyper-parameters optimally, and tested with enough random initializations. All these things take a lot of effort. Why not try to replicate the results in the paper first?

Comment: I was thinking so, @Bill. But, the problem they used in their paper is quite advanced like convection and diffusion equation, which I want to avoid for my first trial as it need some knowledge of PDE which I haven't remembered so well.

Answer (score 0):

after checking your code, I have a question about test dataset; I am not pretty sure if the reason why your preds are bad is because you did not add model.eval()
I am not familiar with this net/model, but as my exp with cnn and basic gcn, I tended to use model.eval() to predict for my result (oriange line on your graph)

For example, if I were you, I would do:

```
for i in range(500):
    model.train()
    yh = model(x_PDE)
    loss = model.loss_PDE(x_PDE) # use mean squared error
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    if i%(500/10)==0:
        print(loss)
        model.eval()
        -- your test function just like your train but without backward optim --
```

I am not sure if this will effect on your answer

Answer (score 0):

It is such nice coincidence that I have been studying *PINN*s these days. It is indeed complex and time-consuming, as stated in the comments, to debug and point out the tricky parts of the model. However, I tried to solve your problem on my own. I created a model on *PyTorch* with two hidden layers with 64 units each and `Tanh()` activation function after each layer. I hope this helps:

```
class CreateDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):

  def __init__(self, dataset):

    self.t = dataset[0]
    self.length = self.t.shape[0]

  def __len__(self):

    return self.length

  def __getitem__(self, index):

    return self.t[index]

PI = np.pi
SEED = 7
EPOCHS = 10000
BATCH_SIZE = 100
torch.manual_seed(SEED)

def initial_condition_loss(model, t):

  t0 = torch.tensor(BATCH_SIZE * [[0.0]])
  t1 = torch.tensor(BATCH_SIZE * [[2 * PI]])

  return torch.square(model(t0)) + torch.square(model(t1))

def residual_loss(model, t):

  t.requires_grad_(True)

  u = model(t)
  u_t = torch.autograd.grad(torch.sum(u), t, retain_graph=True, create_graph=True)[0]

  return torch.square(u_t - torch.cos(t))

def total_loss(model, t):

  return torch.sum(initial_condition_loss(model, t) + residual_loss(model, t))

t = torch.empty((100, 1))
t.uniform_(0.0, 15.0)

t_dataset = CreateDataset([t])

t_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(t_dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)

def set_weight(weights):

  return torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(weights)

def set_bias(biases):

  return torch.nn.init.zeros_(biases)

def set_activation():

  return torch.nn.Tanh()

model = # YOUR MODEL HERE!!!

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())

def training(model, data_loader, epochs):

  model.train()

  for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):

    loss_value = 0.0

    for t in data_loader:

      loss = total_loss(model, t)
      loss.backward()
      optimizer.step()
      optimizer.zero_grad()
      loss_value += loss.item()

    loss_value /= len(data_loader)

    if epoch % 1000 == 0:

      print(f'Epoch: {epoch} - Loss: {loss_value}')

def prediction(model, dataset):

  model.eval()

  y = model(dataset)

  return y
```

Observing the loss:

```
Epoch: 1000 - Loss: 0.997127115726471
Epoch: 2000 - Loss: 0.011104697361588478
Epoch: 3000 - Loss: 0.0016031203558668494
Epoch: 4000 - Loss: 0.0007361933821812272
Epoch: 5000 - Loss: 0.0004778479633387178
Epoch: 6000 - Loss: 0.00038485831464640796
Epoch: 7000 - Loss: 0.0003462266467977315
Epoch: 8000 - Loss: 0.0003259943041484803
Epoch: 9000 - Loss: 0.14281785488128662
Epoch: 10000 - Loss: 0.00029919209191575646
```

Checking the result:

```
plot_data = torch.arange(0.0, 15.0, 0.001).reshape((-1, 1))

u = prediction(model, plot_data)

plt.plot(plot_data, u.detach(), 'bo', markersize=1.75)
plt.show()
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWhg4.png)